# unfortunately ___ has stopped , but logcat contains many errors

Tags: android

i have developped an application android that contains two activities , the first activity contains two Edittext and a login button , i have to enter the value 'abcd'  as a username and 'EFGH' as a password and validate with the button , the probleme is when i clicked login the application has crashed  ,
the error message is : unfortunately ___ is stopped

> logcat:  errors 11-15 19:22:56.237 783-783/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
>   11-15 19:24:41.057 783-783/info.adem.tplogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  Process: info.adem.tplogin, PID: 783
>                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{info.adem.tplogin/info.adem.tplogin.FriendActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                      at info.adem.tplogin.FriendActivity.onCreate(FriendActivity.java:27)
>                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: add the logcat and code

Comment: how can i add them ?

Comment: add info as text via editing your post

Comment: this is the logcat

Comment: 11-15 19:22:56.237 783-783/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
11-15 19:24:41.057 783-783/info.adem.tplogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: info.adem.tplogin, PID: 783
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.adem.tplogin/info.adem.tplogin.FriendActiv

Comment: it is still long i will keep sending the texts until the end of the log cat

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794

Comment: your button is null

Comment: this is manifest file<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.adem.tplogin">

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FriendActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: guys is there a way to send my code to you to check where is the error , because like that it is difficult to resolve the problem

Comment: handleMessage(msg);
if (traceTag != 0) {
                    Trace.traceEnd(traceTag);
                }

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object
```

Before you use a reference from your button to add an event, you need to retrieve the reference from it.

Like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_layout)

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button_id)
        //button.setOnClickListener........
    }

}
```